# Installing IronRuby on Mac

Tags: macos, mono, ironruby

I'm trying to get IronRuby installed on a Mac and having trouble getting it to compile.  If I try to build it using MonoDevelop or to compile it directly with xbuild, I get a messaging saying the compiler is crashing while compiling the Microsoft.Dynamic project.  When I try to do the rake scripts, I get the message saying I need pkg-config.  I tried to find install instructions for pkg-config but coming up short.

Does anyone know of a good resources on how to compile the current version of IronRuby using the current version of Mono/MonoDevelop on a Mac?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Make sure you have installed the latest stable or trunk version of [Mono](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html) available for [Mac OS X](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:OSX)

2) Download the latest IronRuby source code from Github [here](http://github.com/ironruby/ironruby)

3) Unpack the tarball(tar.gz) or zip archive(.zip) file downloaded, then open a terminal in the source directory just extracted (i.e. ironruby-ironruby-b871551/)

4) Try to compile using **xbuild /p:TreatWarningsAsErrors=false Solutions/Ruby.sln**
(I'm using Mono 2.6.7 and when I try to compile the build fails because there is no /usr/bin/dmcs command in this version, so you need to compile [Mono from Github code](http://github.com/mono/mono) or from this [Trunk source](http://mono.ximian.com/monobuild/snapshot/sources-trunk/) see this [README](http://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/README) file and also [READ THIS](http://mono-project.com/Compiling_Mono) )

5) If building from the main IronRuby git repository doesn't work you have two alternatives, one is described [here](http://wiki.github.com/ironruby/ironruby/building#wiki_building-mono), which requires you to use a different branch, and the second alternative is described [here](http://wp.colliertech.org/cj/?p=773)

I successfully compiled IronRuby using the second alternative using Mono 2.6.7 on my openSUSE 64-bit KDE desktop box.

Additional resources :

[Building IronRuby with Mono on OSX](http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/building-ironruby-with-mono-os)

[Getting Started with IronRuby](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1564484&seqNum=1) by the author of [IronRuby Unleashed](http://www.informit.com/title/0672330784)

[IronRuby, Mono and My Mac](http://accidentaltechnologist.com/ironruby/ironruby-mono-and-my-mac/)

Alternatives:

[MacRuby](http://www.macruby.org/)

[JRuby](http://jruby.org/) ([Getting Started with JRuby](http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/GettingStarted))

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response.  I'll go through these items and such tonight to see if I can push through (which I suspect that I can).  Thanks again and will let you know how it goes.

Comment: I ended up having to use the second alternative as well but afterwards it worked on OSX.  Thanks!